# How to set a variable depending on which nodeList is not empty in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, nodelist, selectors-api

I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to do this:

I'm trying to set `target` to either `"[data-update]"` or `div.ui-content` to be found within an element.

Originally I wanted to do something like this:

```
target = el.querySelectorAll("[data-update]") || el.querySelectorAll("div.ui-content");
```

But this will not work, because the first expression will always be defined, even if it is an empty nodeList `[]`.

So now I have this, which works, but I'm not happy with it:

```
target = container.querySelectorAll("[data-update]")

if (target.length === 0) {
  target = container.querySelectorAll("div.ui-content");
}

if (target.length === 0) {
  util.errorHandler({"error": "updatePageSection: No target found"});
} else {
  // do stuff
}
```

**Question**:
Is there an easier way to do this? Pure JavaScript only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the conditional operator, and check the length of the selection:

```
target = el.querySelectorAll("[data-update]").length
     ? el.querySelectorAll("[data-update]")
     : el.querySelectorAll("div.ui-content");
```

Basically `a ? b : c` means *if a is true, take b, else take c*. More infor on: [Contional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Besides, if you don't want to repeat the first selection, you can add an extra step:

```
target = el.querySelectorAll("[data-update]");
target = target.length ? target : el.querySelectorAll("div.ui-content");
```

The first tme you see this syntax is really strange. But you'll soon get used to it.

NOTE: in JavaScript, zero is treated as false. And a none-zero number is treated as true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
target = ( el.querySelectorAll("[data-update]").length>0 && 
           el.querySelectorAll("[data-update]") ) || 
         ( el.querySelectorAll("div.ui-content").length> 0 && 
           el.querySelectorAll("div.ui-content") );
```

But it is absolutely unreadable and too much DOM calls. But "one-line".
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3X2Nd/